# Tikz Table automatic enumeration

Tags: tikz-pgf, tables, enumerate

I have a Table in Tikz where the first column is a consecutive enumeration i.e.

```
\documentclass[12pt,twoside]{report}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix,shadings,arrows,decorations.markings,decorations.pathmorphing}
\tikzset{
    table/.style={
        matrix of nodes,
        row sep=-\pgflinewidth,
        column sep=-\pgflinewidth,
        nodes={
            rectangle,
            draw=black,
            align=center,
                        text width=10em,
                        fill=gray!10,
                   },
                        %baseline={([yshift=-0.5ex]current bounding box.center)},
        %minimum height=1.0em,
        %text depth=0.2em,
        %text height=0.8em,
                %text centered,
        nodes in empty cells,
                row 1/.style={nodes={fill=black, text=white, font=\bfseries}},
                row 2/.style={nodes={text height=3.3ex}},
            }
        }


\begin{document}

Hello World...
\begin{table}
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}
\matrix[table, ampersand replacement=\&] (TabA1)
{
1 \& A2 \& A3 \\
2 \& $10^{2^{3^{4^{5}}}}$ \& B3 \\
3 \& A2 \& A3 \\
4 \& A2 \& A3 \\
5 \& A2 \& A3 \\
6 \& A2 \& A3 \\
7 \& A2 \& A3 \\
8 \& A2 \& A3 \\
};
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{Glossary}
\label{tabA1}
\end{table}


\end{document}
```

How can this be done automatically? I guess using a counter or is there a very simple solution in tikz?

Comment: Done Big Brother ;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can add a style for the first column:

```
column 1/.style={nodes={node contents={\the\pgfmatrixcurrentrow}}}
```

Note that the nodes in the first column do not accept additional contents anymore.

Full MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt,twoside]{report}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix,shadings,arrows,decorations.markings,decorations.pathmorphing}
\tikzset{
    table/.style={
        matrix of nodes,
        row sep=-\pgflinewidth,
        column sep=-\pgflinewidth,
        nodes={
            rectangle,
            draw=black,
            align=center,
                        text width=10em,
                        fill=gray!10,
                   },
                        %baseline={([yshift=-0.5ex]current bounding box.center)},
        %minimum height=1.0em,
        %text depth=0.2em,
        %text height=0.8em,
                %text centered,
        nodes in empty cells,
                row 1/.style={nodes={fill=black, text=white, font=\bfseries}},
                row 2/.style={nodes={text height=3.3ex}},
                column 1/.style={nodes={node contents={\the\pgfmatrixcurrentrow}}},
            }
        }


\begin{document}

Hello World...
\begin{table}
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}
\matrix[table, ampersand replacement=\&] (TabA1)
{
 \& A2 \& A3 \\
 \& $10^{2^{3^{4^{5}}}}$ \& B3 \\
 \& A2 \& A3 \\
 \& A2 \& A3 \\
 \& A2 \& A3 \\
 \& A2 \& A3 \\
 \& A2 \& A3 \\
 \& A2 \& A3 \\
};
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{Glossary}
\label{tabA1}
\end{table}


\end{document}
```

Comment: Do I need to specify this globally or can I also just add it to this one tikzpicture? So basically [table, ampersand replacement=\&, column 1/.style...]

Comment: @Diger You can add it to a specific matrix, as you suggest.

Comment: The `\numexpr` isn't necessary by the way.

Comment: What is it for?

Comment: @TorbjørnT. Thanks for the heads-up, I will remove it.

Comment: So what does `\numexpr` do?

Comment: @Diger it turns the expression that follows it into a numeric (integer) expression, I believe. For more information see [the e-TeX manual](http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/etex/base/etex_man.pdf). Apparently `\pgfmatrixcurrentrow` is already an integer, which seems reasonable. The `\the` command is used to typeset the expression.